# My J2me application working correctly in simulator but not working correctly in Mobile phone

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, midp, lcdui

I developed a J2ME project using sun java wireless toolkit 2.5.2_01 for CLDC.

In my project I display a form namely `TableForm`. Inside that form I display a table `CustomItemTable`. This table I created using `javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem`.

The table ("CustomItemTable") had the buttons "EDIT CELL", "SAVE CELL".

What I am trying to achieve is if table loaded the button "SAVE CELL" is not there. After clicking the "EDIT CELL" button the "SAVE CELL" button enabled. Then the user should be able to edit the cell values inside the table itself (like an excel sheet).

For editing it is not go to another form.

After clicking "SAVE CELL". Then the "EDIT CELL" is appeared and "SAVE CELL" is removed. The edit mode is become false. Then he is not able to edit the cell. For editing he click the "EDIT CELL" again.

Here I should display the table with respect to the screen size. If user clicks right button from the last column in the displaying table then if any column present right side means the table moves right. Like that move up/down/left works.

Here  is one problem is **all the above operations is working in simulator correctly. But it is not working correctly in my testing mobile phone.**

In a mobile if user comes the last column then click right means *the table does not move to the right*. Actually it by default (automatically) assume that "EDIT CELL" button is clicked and performs that respective event of "EDIT CELL".

I don't know why it is happening. How should I prevent this? How should I make my application working in mobile like working as in simulator?

I am using mobile for testing is "Nokia 7230".

Comment: In other words: (i) get rid of all the bold-face; (ii) get rid of all the ***'s; (iii) paragraph it appropriately; (iv) correct all your spelling mistakes. At the moment you really have no hope of a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.The problem is in my application (in my logic).Now i changed my application (my logic to display table and even handling) .

Now its working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your question is garbled. go slow. anyway probably it is a display layout problem. are you using Canvas?